# How to make only one document write to Firestore using GeoFirestore

Tags: java, android, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore, geofirestore

I have the next code (in kotlin), following the `README` at [geofirestore-android](https://github.com/imperiumlabs/GeoFirestore-Android), that writes the geopoint and geohash to an existing firestore document.

```
val collectionRef = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection("ExistingCollectionUID")
val geoFirestore = GeoFirestore(collectionRef)
geoFirestore.setLocation("ExistingDocumentUID",GeoPoint(37.587,-122.405)){ exception ->
    if (exception != null){
        Log.d(TAG,"Location saved on server successfully!")
    }
}
```

The flow I am follow currently is:

1. Write user info to a new document in Firestore
2. Add GeoFirestore information to that document

This result in two writes into Firestore, doubling the price of the bill.

**is there a way I can attach GeoFirestore information to the other document info and make only one write into Firestore?**

Comment: I just went thought the [Geo lib](https://github.com/imperiumlabs/GeoFirestore-Android) and I don't think there's any method which can help you with this. You can create an issue in lib repo and hopefully the author will add a method to create and store a document object with geopoint.

Comment: I already open an [issue](https://github.com/imperiumlabs/GeoFirestore-Android/issues/42) there, thankyou!